# geforce 3050 RTX eagle 8g fan always at full speed

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, fan

I just upgraded my wifes computer GPU. Installed the latest driver and the fan seems to be always at full speed. GPU-z does not see the fan speed and gives me 0 RPM. I downgraded driver by 1 version and the fan went quiet. Then i did a test and gave GPU some load. The fan sped up. But once the load was gone, even after cooling the GPU down, fan is still max speed. Is the Driver broken or is the GPU fan speed controller broken? Or maybe something else?

This is the motherboard MSI B85-G41 PC MATE ATX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I decided to do a physical check on the graphics card to see if everything is correctly connected. I found that 1 of the PSU power connector wires was against 1 of the fans, stopping it from spinning. So i re-arranged the wires so that nothing would obstruct the fans, and it fixed now.

Comment: Consider accepting your answer as the accepted one if you're happy with the solution :)

Comment: @GChuf YEa sorry. Forgot about this. I couldnt accept it right away, had to wait  2 days.